# How to ensure a settings file is secure in Python?

Tags: python, powershell, security, subprocess, settings

I'm sorry if this question has been answered already but I can't seem to find a solution. (Many questions about settings files in general, and even some mentioning this problem, but none addressing it)

I have a Python program which will be running a Powershell script as a subprocess. (Python handling the GUI, Powershell doing the grunt work to schedule tasks etc.)

My query is whether there is a safe way to have a settings file that contains parameters for the Powershell script that can be loaded into Python and is resistant to malicious code injection? The only way I can think of is to encrypt the settings file which is fine, but then you lose the ability to quickly change the settings without going through the GUI. Is there a smart way to solve this?

When calling Powershell I use the simple:

```
subprocess.Popen(['powershell.exe', args], 
                   stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Perhaps there is a better way of doing this to shield against *args* having unintended code in it?

Any answers are greatly appreciated! Thanks! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to make sure your settings file is secure is to save *configuration* instead of *code* or *arguments*. (Arguments for `powershell.exe` are essentially code.)

Storing powershell arguments in your config file is wrong for two reasons:

1. It's prone to code injection.
2. It sounds like Powershell is not an essential part of your program; it's an implementation detail. If you ever decide to replace powershell with something else that does the grunt work, your config file will be useless.

Instead, you should store *data*. Data that is undoubtedly just data, and not code in any shape or form. You can then *create* an appropriate powershell command from this data, if and when you need it.

For example, instead of saving the powershell arguments `sleep 3; echo Hello`, you should save only the values that are necessary to reconstruct this powershell command. One option would be a JSON file like this:

```
{
    "delay": 3,
    "text_to_display": "Hello"
}
```

You can easily reconstruct the command `sleep 3; echo Hello` from these values, and nothing dangerous can happen if someone modifies your config file, because it's not *code*. (As long as you shell-escape these values when you convert them into code.)

---

In the rare case that you *actually* have to store code in your config file (for example because you're writing a task scheduler), you're basically out of luck. You can try to make code injection more difficult by encrypting the config file, but in the end that's just an annoyance for an attacker and it doesn't provide any real security (unless you let the user choose the password, but then you have to prompt the user for the password every time they use your program).

**If you ever store code in a config file, you have to live with the associated dangers of code injection. Make sure you and your users are aware of the risk.**